# script to read .rtf file, find string and insert into DB table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, rtf

I need to come up with SSIS script task in C# that will read a .rtf file and import two things as below

[image: like this]

Please suggest ways I can do this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Also it would be helpful to see that acual RTF file you want to get the data from.

Comment: Welcome. As it stands this question isn't a good fit for stack overflow because it essentially asks for creation of an entire system to solve a problem. Questions here generally have short, factual answers and are isolated to specific problems, errors or ways of doing a unit task. What you need to do is devise a design for your entire app, set about implementing it and come ask us about any specific issues. Work to the rule of thumb: if it would take you more than a minute to explain the problem to a work colleague, and it would take him more than a minute to answer, your question is too broad

Comment: I don't know much about C# but what I found is   public void Main()
  {
   // TODO: Add your code here
            using(OpenFileDialog ofd=new OpenFileDialog(){Filter="Rich Text Format|*.rtf",ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false}) 

   Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }

Comment: @Vivan_J can you explain why SSIS is relevant here?

Comment: We don't have other tools..I mean we are using only SQL Server

Comment: Hi All, Till now I have done..used RichTextBox().. saved it in .txt using WriteAllText() then using StreamReader() read contain of lines and save that two things in db table. not sure this is long route or not..